# CreateUser with special role in database

Tags: mongodb

I am struggling with the MongoDB authorization system. I have an application with must execute some very precise defined db.eval() statements. As we all know, this function requires special privileges.

I tried

```
use admin
db.createRole({ role: "dbEval", privileges: [{ resource: {anyResource: true}, actions: ["anyAction"]}], roles:[ { role: "readWrite", db: "test" }]})

use test
db.createUser({ user: "default", pwd: "default", roles: [ { role: "dbEval", db: "test" }] })
```

But I get the error message

**Error: couldn't add user: No role named dbEval@test**

How can I create a user in "admin" and let him allow "dbEval" role to be used in "test"?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a deprecated function. Are you sure you want to use that? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I know that it is deprecated, but my application "constructs" the command and data dynamically based on the client call. Unfortunately, there are no other ways to implement a kind of "stored procedures" in MongoDB. But in my application, I know the exact db.xxx() command I create, so there is no security concern in using the db.eval().